# Best bound on this term

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, asymptotics

Suppose we have the term
$$\min\big\{A^2, \frac 1{B^2}\big\}(1+BA)$$
with $A\in\mathbb N$ and $0\leqslant B \leqslant 1$.

What is the best bound I can get on this quantity in the form $O(A^k$)? Bounding trivially we have $O(A^3)$, but this is insufficient for my purposes. It feels like the minimum and the term $BA$ are acting against each other, so the bound should be better, but I don't know how to translate my intuition to an actual better bound.

Comment: That min makes it so uncertain.

Comment: @RossMillikan What if $B=0$?

Comment: @ċuqlajta: I would hope that is not allowed since we divide by $B$.  The question does not make sense if $B=0$

Comment: But $B$ could be arbitrarily small

Comment: @ċuqlajta But if you let $B$ vary, why do you expect to have a result of the form $O(A^k)$?

Comment: Usually if you are looking for $O(A^k)$ you consider all the other parameters fixed as $A \to \infty$.  Although $B$ can be very small, eventually $A \gt \frac 1B$.  If $B$ is varying with $A$ you need to define that.

Comment: $B$ does not vary with $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $B$, $A^2$ will exceed $\frac 1{B^2}$ eventually and the expression will be about $\frac AB$, so it is $O(A)$